# How to insert values into a table from two tables?

Tags: sql, ms-access

- Using MS office 2019
- I have a specific number of members in an association, each member is included in a specific category. I want to make a table that counts the present and absent members and the total number of the association in each category. –
- tblPerson (idPerson , idCategory)
- tblAbsent (idPerson , idSituation )

```
tblPerson
-----------------------
idPerson | idCategory |
----------------------+
01       |   03       |
02       |   02       |
03       |   03       |
04       |   01       |
05       |   01       |
06       |   01       |
---------+------------+

tblAbsent
----------------------+
idPerson | idSituation|
----------------------+
01       |   02       |
04       |   01       |
05       |   04       |
06       |   01       |
---------+------------+
```

I want to create 3rd table

- tblTotal (idCategory , tblPerson.COUNT(idCategory) AS total , tblAbsent.COUNT(idCategory) AS absent ,total-absent AS present  )

```
tblTotal
-------------------+--------+---------+
idCategory | total | absent | present |
-----------+-------+--------+---------+
01         |  03   |   03   |   00    |
02         |  01   |   00   |   01    |
03         |  02   |   01   |   01    |
-----------+-------+--------+---------+
```

Comment: Why do you show idCategory field in tblAbsent? Should that be idSituation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a simple relationship between the tables.  I would suggest:

```
select p.idCategory,
       count(*) as total,
       count(a.idPerson) as absent,
       (count(*) - count(a.idPerson)) as present
from tblPerson as p left join
     tblAbsent as a
     on p.idPerson = a.idPerson
group by p.idCategory;
```

It is unclear why you are repeating `idCategory` between the two tables.

Comment: I have a specific number of members in an association, each member is included in a specific category.
I want to make a table that counts the present and absent members and the total number of the association in each category.

Comment: @reguiegyounes . . . If you have a working answer to your question, you should accept one of them.

Answer (score 2):

You might use something along the lines of the following:

```
select 
    q.idcategory, 
    q.total,
    count(t.idcategory) as absent,
    q.total-count(t.idcategory) as present
from
    (
        select t.idcategory, count(*) as total
        from tblperson t
        group by t.idcategory
    ) q
    left join tblabsent t on q.idcategory = t.idcategory
group by
    q.idcategory, 
    q.total
order by
    q.idcategory
```

Here, the subquery returns a distinct set of `idcategory` values, and the total number of records within each category.

This subquery is then `left joined` to the `tblabsent` table, and uses the fact that `count([field])` will only count non-null values (whereas `count(*)` will count **all** records) to return the total number of absent/present records.

Comment: select 
    q.idCategory, 
    q.total,
    count(t.idCategory) as absent,
    q.total-count(t.idCategory) as present
from
    (
        select t.idCategory, count(*) as total
        from tblPerson t
        group by t.idCategory
    ) q
    left join (select tblAbsent.idPerson as idPerson, tblPerson.idCategory as idCategory FROM tblPerson inner join tblAbsent  on tblPerson.idPerson=tblAbsent.idPerson) t on q.idCategory = t.idCategory
group by
    q.idCategory, 
    q.total
order by
    q.idCategory

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    q.idcategory, 
    q.total,
    count(t.idcategory) as absent,
    q.total-count(t.idcategory) as present
from
    (
        select t.idcategory, count(*) as total
        from tblperson t
        group by t.idcategory
    ) q
    left join (select tblAbsent.idPerson as idPerson, tblPerson.idCategory as idCategory FROM tblPerson inner join tblAbsent on tblPerson.idPerson=tblAbsent.idPerson)  t on q.idcategory = t.idcategory
group by
    q.idcategory, 
    q.total
order by
    q.idcategory
```